# "Internal Server Error" on Heroku in Django/Mezzanine app

Tags: django, heroku, mezzanine

I'm deploying my Mezzanine app on heroku, and I think I've finally set most things up.

Now though, every page of my app gives an Internal Server Error, and no logs mention anything error-like at all. Same error on local as well.

The logs from the command 'heroku logs' look like this:

```
2014-09-03T07:07:52.555930+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `g
unicorn wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:30978 -w 1`
2014-09-03T07:07:53.900072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to u
p
2014-09-03T07:08:27.706884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=sheplusplus.herokuapp.com request_id=70b72520-1094-4ed7-83d7-ff44277c603b fwd=
"98.234.178.149" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=713
2014-09-03T07:08:29.832027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=sheplusplus.herokuapp.com request_id=5a32f20e-5244-4f15-9e4b-dadd6b0fcfbb fwd=
"98.234.178.149" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=713
2014-09-03T07:08:31.720436+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=sheplusplus.herokuapp.com request_id=9ed6536a-3bb3-4dd9-904c-b2b3f1db2827 fwd=
"98.234.178.149" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=713
```

and the logs from Papertrail look like this:

```
Sep 03 00:07:48 sheplusplus heroku/web.1:  State changed from up to starting 
Sep 03 00:07:51 sheplusplus heroku/web.1:  Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 
Sep 03 00:07:52 sheplusplus heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 0 
Sep 03 00:07:52 sheplusplus heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `gunicorn wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:30978 -w 1` 
Sep 03 00:07:54 sheplusplus heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to up 
Sep 03 00:08:28 sheplusplus heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/" host=sheplusplus.herokuapp.com request_id=70b72520-1094-4ed7-83d7-ff44277c603b fwd="98.234.178.149" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=713 
Sep 03 00:08:30 sheplusplus heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/" host=sheplusplus.herokuapp.com request_id=5a32f20e-5244-4f15-9e4b-dadd6b0fcfbb fwd="98.234.178.149" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=713 
Sep 03 00:08:31 sheplusplus heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/" host=sheplusplus.herokuapp.com request_id=9ed6536a-3bb3-4dd9-904c-b2b3f1db2827 fwd="98.234.178.149" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=713
```

My procfile looks like so:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 1
```

I have no idea how to begin fixing this because I see absolutely nothing wrong.

Comment: Have you correctly provisioned the application? Are you missing any requirements?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by provisioned? And I don't see any missing requirements but I will check again.

Comment: @BurnhanKhalid I have checked and I don't see any missing requirements. Any other ideas of what could be going wrong?

Comment: Apparently there is a syntax error, but all gunicorn will tell me is that it is near a '('.

Answer (score 0):

locally do:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And watch the output when you load a page.  It should expose the error in a clearer message.